# Reveal toggle hide other div jquery

Tags: jquery, toggle, slidetoggle

I have 2 links that both reveal different divs. I've got it slide toggling all fine. But what i need it to do is collapse the opposite toggle (if it's open). Similar to how an accordion panel works (when you trigger a reveal toggle link the open panel closes and the newly triggered panel opens).

Here's the jQuery I'm currently using

```
//Left reveal toggle
$(".left-reveal-toggle").on("click", function () {
    $('.left-reveal-section').slideToggle("slow");
    $(".left-reveal-toggle").toggleClass("active");
});

//Right reveal toggle
$(".right-reveal-toggle").on("click", function () {
    $('.right-reveal-section').slideToggle("slow");
    $(".right-reveal-toggle").toggleClass("active");
});
```

Here's a working JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/wq73aeuh/1/

```js
//Left reveal toggle
$(".left-reveal-toggle").on("click", function() {
  $('.left-reveal-section').slideToggle("slow");
  $(".left-reveal-toggle").toggleClass("active");
});

//Right reveal toggle
$(".right-reveal-toggle").on("click", function() {
  $('.right-reveal-section').slideToggle("slow");
  $(".right-reveal-toggle").toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.left-panel {
  min-height: 400px;
  background: #31b9ce;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.right-panel {
  min-height: 400px;
  background: #4f5cd6;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.left-panel-reveal {
  min-height: 400px;
  background: #31b9ce;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.right-panel-reveal {
  min-height: 400px;
  background: #4f5cd6;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
  font-size: 0px;
  line-height: 0px;
  display: block;
}

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
font,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left-panel">
  <a href="#" class="left-reveal-toggle">Read more form left panel</a>
</div>

<div class="right-panel">
  <a href="#" class="right-reveal-toggle">Read more from right panel</a>
</div>


<div class="clear"></div>


<div class="left-reveal-section hide">
  <div class="left-panel-reveal">left panel reveal content</div>
  <div class="right-panel-reveal">left panel reveal content</div>
</div>


<div class="right-reveal-section hide">
  <div class="left-panel-reveal">right panel reveal content</div>
  <div class="right-panel-reveal">right panel reveal content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Give them a common class and close any :visible before opening

Comment: Hi, can you explain in a little more detail what you mean please?

Answer (score 0):

Use at the top of function in right:
    $('.left-reveal-section').slideUp('slow'); 
And top of function in left:
    $('.right-reveal-section').slideUp('slow');

Comment: Thanks for this. It works great. I do have 1 small issue. When the toggle links are pressed the alternate divs collapse as per your slideUp function but the toggle link still has 'active' class added. It also needs to remove the active class. Here's an updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wq73aeuh/6/ Sorry if it's changed slightly from my original post.

Comment: No problem, after slideUp()  add .toggleClass("active");  like this: $('.left-reveal-section').slideUp('slow').toggleClass("active"); and the same for the right