# $($(this).attr("href")).slideDown(); Tab Collapse

Tags: jquery, tabs

I've got a tabbed section which is working great. But if you click an open tab i want it to collapse the content div. So if .left-reveal-toggle content is displaying and you click that tab i want it to close 'Read More' and no content to display. Rather than it always forcing a tab content area to display after initial click. On load you see 2 tabbed box links. If you click the left "Read More" link the content for that link appears below. If you click the same link again i'd like the content below to display none. At the minute it collapses then re-opens.

```
$(".tab").click(function () {
    $("#tabbed-content .tab-content").slideUp(500);
    $($(this).attr("href")).slideDown(500);
    $(".tab").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wq73aeuh/12/

Comment: Expected behavior is not well explained, not entirely clear what problem is

Comment: Edit the question to make it more absolute ( and clear), not just in a comment

Comment: Is this not a duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43140791/reveal-toggle-hide-other-div-jquery